# Using ConsistentErrorHandler as the Memcache error handler in objectify 3.1?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, objectify

Is there a way to use the ConsistentErrorHandler in the 3.1 implementation of objectify. I've started seeing some memcache errors in my apps and want the default behaviour to be to ignore those exceptions. Looking at this bug report (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6236) on appengine, it seems they didn't fix the initial bug but instead added a way to ignore the exceptions if the ConsistentErrorHandler is set.

Is it possible to get Objecitfy to set ConsistentErrorHandler as the memcache handler when creating an objectify instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on the objectify google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/objectify-appengine/memcache/objectify-appengine/HbggddpAka0/_9ODKTnwswcJ